# Problem with pgfkeys

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

Perhaps a stupid mistake but the results are different, why ? I want the nodes on a horizontal line.
If I comment `\pgfqkeys{/LX}{#1}` then the result is fine (the nodes are on horizontal line)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfkeys{/LX/.cd,
        frac/.store in              = \Xfrac, %not used
        frac                        = 0,
        /LX/.search also            = {/tikz}, 
}  

\def\labelX[#1](#2,#3){%
\pgfqkeys{/LX}{#1}% ok if I comment this line
\foreach \p in {#2,...,#3}{%
    \path[shift = {(\p,0)}] (0pt,5 pt)--(0pt,-5 pt) 
                            node[/LX/.cd,#1]{\p};}
    \ifnum\Xfrac=1 \node at (0,1){Test frac =1};
    \else \node at (0,1){Test frac =0};
    \fi
}

\def\labelXb[#1](#2,#3){%
\pgfqkeys{/LX}{#1}
\foreach \p in {#2,...,#3}{%
    \path[shift={(\p,0)}] (0pt,5 pt)--(0pt,-5 pt)
                          node[/LX/.cd,#1,rotate=-30]{\p};}
    \ifnum\Xfrac=1 \node at (0,1){Test frac =1};
    \else \node at (0,1){Test frac =0};
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \labelX[frac=1,red,rotate=-30](0,5)
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \labelXb[frac=0,blue,draw](0,5)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since LX doesn't understand `rotate` it `search also` TikZ and the transformation becomes rotate -30 which is how much the nodes are rotated.

Comment: @percusse I agree with your remark but why in the second case the line is horizontal and not in the first

Comment: In the second case rotate=-30 only applied to the node but not to the path. In the first one the rotate is set for the current scope to every item since you use `\pgfqkeys`.

Comment: It' s not possible to modify the first method to get a line horizontal? With pgf 2.1 and tkz-euclide 1.16 I used something like that and you can see in the doc that I don't have this problem !

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, let's keep track of the transformations: Assume the argument `#1` holds only `rotate=-30` for simplicity.

```
\def\labelX[#1](#2,#3){%
\pgfqkeys{/LX}{#1}% Here it is equivalent to \tikzset{rotate=-30}
\foreach \p in {#2,...,#3}{%
     %
     % Here still rotate=-30 is enforced hence the path below obeys the rotation.
     %
     \path[shift = {(\p,0)}] (0pt,5 pt)--(0pt,-5 pt) 
                            node[/LX/.cd,#1]{\p};}
     %
     %We can also see the rotation from something at the origin that won't rotate
     %
     %
     \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] {}
     %
     \ifnum\Xfrac=1 \node[transform shape,draw] at (0,1){Test frac =1};
     \else \node at (0,1){Test frac =0};
     \fi
}
```

[image]

The easiest way is to reset the transformations (or at least only the nontranslational ones)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\pgfkeys{/LX/.cd,
        frac/.store in              = \Xfrac, %not used
        frac                        = 0,
        /LX/.search also            = {/tikz}, 
}  

\def\labelX[#1](#2,#3){%
\pgfqkeys{/LX}{#1}
\foreach \p in {#2,...,#3}{%
\pgftransformresetnontranslations%                <------------
    \path[shift = {(\p,0)}] (0pt,5 pt)--(0pt,-5 pt) 
                            node[/LX/.cd,#1]{\p};}
    \ifnum\Xfrac=1 \node at (0,1){Test frac =1};
    \else \node at (0,1){Test frac =0};
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \labelX[frac=1,red,rotate=-30](0,5)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ok but now I don't understand why I got the good result in the doc of  tkz-base page 16 and 17

Comment: @AlainMatthes You are saving the `label options` in a macro and insert them only into the node as you have done in `node[xlabel style,fill = \tkz@fillcolor,cmd@X@option]}tkz@temp{\tkz@Xshowgradresult};` hence it is only valid for the node itself. In your first example on this question you are setting a global transformation by setting the key.

Comment: I forgot that ! with `/LX/.search also            = {/tikz}, ` I can use the styles from Tikz but It's very difficult to manage all the keys. The easiest solution seems to be to use a style like `\tikzset{xlabel style/.append style={rotate=-30}}` and  `node[xlabel style,/LX/.cd,#1]`